Force https, non-www, and turn queries into paths
I posted a fairly incoherent request for help, which has been received. I have now gotten something that seems to work. It forces the use of "https://" in place of "http://; forces "example.org" in place of "www.example.org:" and removes "FramesVar.html?" from a URL with a nameless query string. I would appreciate some advice and/or correction. One question, is the [NC] needed?
For example, doing all of these things at once causes
"http://www.gilbertmunger.org/FrameVars.html?Pages/ID43.h
to become
"https://gilbertmunger.org/Pages/ID43.html"
(I have gotten rid of frames, but there are anchors using them still hiding in other sites.)
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gilbertmunger.org/%{QUERY_STRING} [QSD,R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.gilbertmunger\.org$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://gilbertmunger.org/$1 [R=301,L]

MANY THANKS.
I tried many formulations until this one seems to be working.
